# RavenDB - How to merge related docs of same type into an index projection

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, ravendb

Assuming the following class:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string KeyId { get; set; }
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
}
```

and the following result class:

```
public class ProjectedThing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string KeyId { get; set; }
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}
```

How can I build an index that holds the result class?

The closest I've come is with the following index definition:

```
public class ProjectedThings : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Thing,ProjectedThing>
{
    public ProjectedThings()
    {
        Map = docs => from doc in docs
                    select new
                    {
                        Title = doc.Title,
                        KeyId = doc.KeyId,
                        Culture = doc.Culture,
                        Things = new[] { 
                            new Thing{
                                Id = doc.Id,
                                Title = doc.Title,
                                KeyId = doc.KeyId,
                                Culture = doc.Culture,
                                TitlePluralized = doc.TitlePluralized
                            }
                        }
                    };

        Reduce = results => from r in results
                            group r by r.KeyId into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Title = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == x.KeyId).Title,
                                KeyId = g.Key,
                                Culture = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == x.KeyId).Culture,
                                Things = from thing in g.SelectMany(x => x.Things).Where(x => x.Id != x.KeyId)
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   Id = thing.Id,
                                                   Title = thing.Title,
                                                   KeyId = thing.Key,
                                                   Culture = thing.Culture
                                               }
                            };
    }
}
```

That's almost doing the trick, but I can't collect the Title, KeyId, and Culture in the reduction. Only the Things property is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == x.KeyId)
```

I don't understand this, but this is likely to be always false.
You probably want:

```
    g.FirstOrDefault().Title,
```